# Multiprocessing errors in OS X with python2.7 on pre-El Capitan machines

Tags: python, macos, multiprocessing

The context for this is much, much too big for an SO question so the code below is a extremely simplified demonstration of the actual implementation.

Generally, I've written an extensive module for academic contexts that launches a subprocess at runtime to be used for event scheduling. When a script or program using this module closes on pre-El Capitan machines my efforts to join the child process fail, as do my last-ditch efforts to just kill the process; OS X gives a "Python unexpectedly quit" error and the the orphaned process persists. **I am very much a nub to multiprocessing**, without a CS background; diagnosing this is beyond me.

*If I am just too ignorant, I'm more than willing to go RTFM; specific directions welcome.*

I'm *pretty* sure this example is coherent & representative, but, know that the actual project works flawlessly on El Capitan, works during runtime on everything else, but consistently crashes as described when quitting. I've tested it with absurd time-out values (30 sec+); always the same result.

One last note: I started this with python's default multiprocessing libraries, then switched to [billiard](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/billiard/3.3.0.23) as a dev friend suggested it might run smoother. To date, I've not experienced any difference.

**UPDATE:**
Had omitted the function that gives the `@threaded` decorator purpose; now present in code.

Generally, we have:

```
shared_queue = billiard.Queue()  # or multiprocessing, have used both

class MainInstanceParent(object):
     def __init__(self):
        # ..typically init stuff..
        self.event_ob = EventClass(self) # gets a reference to parent

     def quit():
         try:
            self.event_ob.send("kkbai")
            started = time.time()
            while time.time - started < 1:  # or whatever
                self.event_ob.recieve()
            if self.event_ob.event_p.is_alive():
                raise RuntimeError("Little bugger still kickin'")
          except RuntimeError:
              os.kill(self.event_on.event_p.pid, SIGKILL)

class EventClass(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        # moar init stuff
        self.parent = parent
        self.pipe, child = Pipe()
        self.event_p = __event_process(child)

    def receive():
        self.pipe.poll()
        t = self.pipe.recv()
        if isinstance(t, Exception):
            raise t
        return t

    def send(deets):
        self.pipe.send(deets)

def threaded(func):
    def threaded_func(*args, **kwargs):
        p = billiard.Process(target=func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        p.start()
        return p
    return threaded_func    

@threaded
def __event_process(pipe):
    while True:
        if pipe.poll():
            inc = pipe.recv()
            # do stuff conditionally on what comes through
            if inc == "kkbai":
                return
            if inc == "meets complex condition to pass here":
                 shared_queue.put("stuff inferred from inc")
```

Comment: What does `@threaded` do? Except from creating the `Queue`, your code snippet doesn't seem to use `billiard`.

Comment: @RolandSmith Ridiculous oversight, sorry; fixed.

Comment: Also, I don't see any `join`?

Comment: @RolandSmith My (naive) understanding is that the process doesn't have to be explicitly joined if a signal for it to self-terminate is given (ie. the `return` statement effectively executes the `join` call automatically). I can't currently seem to find where I'd read this, however....

Comment: @RolandSmith Found it; perhaps I've misunderstood it though: I'm referring to the `join_thread()` description (last line). https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Pipe

Comment: Looking at `multiprocessing/process.py`, the `Process.join` method is *not* called in `Process.run`. AFAICT, it is called nowhere in the whole multiprocessing modules.

Comment: @RolandSmith Hrmm interesting—and thank you; I will read up on how to properly achieve this and see if it resolves my issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before exiting the main program, call `multiprocessing.active_children()` to see how many child processes are still running. This will also `join` the processes that have already quit.

If you would need to signal the children that it's time to quit, create a `multiprocessing.Event` before starting the child processes. Give it a meaningful name like `children_exit`. The child processes should regularly call `children_exit.is_set()` to see if it is time for them to quit. In the main program you call `children_exit.set()` to signal the child processes.

**Update:**

Have a good look through the *Programming guidelines* in the `multiprocessing` documentation;

- It is best to provide the abovementioned `Event` objects as argument to the `target` of the `Process` initializer for reasons mentioned in those guidelines.
- If your code also needs to run on ms-windows, you have to jump through some extra hoop, since that OS doesn't do `fork()`.

**Update 2:**

On your `PyEval_SaveThread` error; could you modify your question to show the complete trace or alternatively could you post it somewhere?
Since `multiprocessing` uses threads internally, this is probably the culprit, unless you are also using threads somewhere.

If you also use threads note that GUI toolkits in general and tkinter in particular are *not* thread safe. Tkinter calls should therefore *only* be made from one thread!

How much work would it be to port your code to Python 3? If it is a bug in Python 2.7, it might be already fixed in the current (as of now) Python 3.5.1.

Comment: So having implemented this, and on reading up a little, agreed that this is what I ought to be doing, I unfortunately find no change in my code's behavior. The exit trace offers `Fatal Python error: PyEval_SaveThread: NULL tstate`. A google search for this reveals bugs in both `tkinter` and `numpy` libraries, both of which are in use in my actual dev context. Any ideas here—are these libraries likely to actually be involved? How to troubleshoot?

Comment: So helpful! Porting to Python 3 isn't a question of the effort, unfortunately, but one of context; 2.7 is and will be the home for this module alas. Tkinter, for sure, is only in use on the main thread. Will add full trace of the exit error shortly.